# Print function in python giving strings with brackets?

Tags: python, arrays, string, brackets

When I print a statement in python it is given in the form ['Hello World']. I'm not certain why and am looking to fix this problem and I believe it may be related to the formatting of the code.

```
query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()
brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
brand = set(brands).intersection(query.split())
brand = str(brand.translate({ord('['): '', ord(']'): ''}))
print(brand)
```

which gives me the output (from the print function) when given a correct query of apple:

```
{'apple'}
```

I would appreciate any solutions,

Thanks,

Python Shell: v3.5.2

Comment: Here is the query command - query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()  - Thanks

Comment: in the third line, brand is a set.  I'm not sure what you are doing in the forth line. Can you explain?

Comment: It's because you made a string out of a set. Just print the items in the set, or do something like `print(*brand)`

Comment: Thanks. :-) In the third line I am looking at the query for a match in the array which if found sets that intersection as the variable brand.

Comment: The third line is OK. The question is what you want to do after that!

Comment: Set objects also don't have a `translate` method. So your code as written shouldn't even run. Not sure what you were trying to achieve anyway.

Comment: The third line was my attempt at fixing the brackets from being printed. May I ask how you set the objects. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces '{' and '}' are used for sets and dictionaries.

```
# e.g.
print(set(brands))
{'apple', 'android', 'windows'}
```

In your case you create a set by intersecting set(brands) with the query, then you convert the set to a string, which will include the curly braces.

One simple solution to exclude the braces, while still separating all possible matches is:

```
brand = set(brands).intersection(query.split())
print(', '.join(brand))
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply, the output was '{, ', a, p, p, l, e, ', }' which still includes the curly brackets. Essentially, the aim of the script is to check the query for a brand. Then using the brand that is found in the query get it into a format which is usable for conditional statements. Ideally, the format I am trying to get to would be a result of just apple. Thanks for your help, Sam :-)

Comment: With my solution you need to remove the line `brand = str(brand.translate({ord('['): '', ord(']'): ''}))`

Comment: Just to throw it out there - would you know of a method to convert that printed output of 'apple' to a variable?

Comment: `foobar = ', '.join(brand)`

Comment: Great - thank you! Would it be ok for you to check out another error I have been having with an exception handler. It is my first time writing a script like this hence the errors. Thanks, Sam

Comment: Sure, though you should probably make a new question.

Comment: Hi, here is the question - thank you URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018875/exception-handler-to-check-if-inline-script-for-variable-worked Sam